# Having trouble removing rows from a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a simple table containing text and inputs. I am trying to determine how many inputs are in the table dynamically by selecting a value from a drop down. This works fine the first time, however when I try to change the value only some of the rows get removed. Here is my code, I have replaced the inputs with the index to more easily see what is going on.

Here is the output, page load[image: page load]

After 6 elements are selected it still looks fine, showing all the rows that were in the table

[image: 6 selected]

Here is where it all goes wrong, although the length of the array is output as 11 only 8 rows are output to the console, and half the old rows get left behind in the table.

[image: final]

Any help would be very much appreciated, I am completely puzzled by this behavior. EDIT: I have added the HTML and removed a bit of the JS, I honestly don't know what to exclude because I don't know what the problem is..

As requested, here is everything, I don't believe the PHP is required as the problem occurs before the form is posted. Thank you all for having a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Create Questions</h1>
        <form name="create" action="process.php" method="POST">

            <table id = "inputTable">
                <tr><td>ID: </td><td><input id="field" name="id" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Text: </td><td><input id="field" name="txt" type="text" /></td></tr>

                <tr><td>#of choices: </td><td><select id="numberOfChoices" name="numberOfChoices">

                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>

                    </select></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Answer: </td><td><input id="field" name="id" type="text" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Points: </td><td><input id="field" name="id" type="number" /></td></tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

        <script>

             window.onload = function () {

    document.querySelector("#numberOfChoices").addEventListener("change", addFields);

        };


        function addFields() {

            var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
            var choices = document.querySelector("#numberOfChoices");
            var choicesValue = choices.value;

            var tab = document.querySelector("#inputTable");

            var rows = tab.rows;
            console.log(rows.length);

            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {

                var row = rows[j];

                console.log(row.cells[0].innerHTML);

                for (var k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
                    var letter = letters[k];


                    if (row.cells[0].innerHTML === letter)
                    {
                        tab.deleteRow(j);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }


            for (var i = 0; i < choicesValue; i++) {

                var row = tab.insertRow(3 + i);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);


                cell1.innerHTML = letters[i];
                //cell2.innerHTML = "<input id=\"field\" name=\"id\" type=\"text\" />"
                cell2.innerHTML = i;

            }


        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you please use a snippet to help you debug the behaviour?

Comment: I apologize, I am not clear on your meaning. Are you asking to see less code, or are you suggesting I use a particular technique? I am very much still learning and am not sure what you mean.

Comment: You need to supply a complete but minimal example of the markup and code here. [mcve]

Comment: OK, I will edit to add the HTML and try to minimize the JS, thank you

Comment: Um, I can't find your problem because I don't have the full picture (ie functioning code that would get me to the point of the problem) Maybe this is an exception to the rule and it might be required that your code be submitted in full? Or perhaps the full code on [Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/),

Comment: I will add everything, there really isn't that much, thank you

Comment: I have added everything, I was hoping I was missing something simple. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is a code viewer which runs the code and output inside the editor. Find the correct button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove some row, the table content is being changed. So removing "a" row leads to reducing table's length by 1 and the next row would be "c", not "b". And that "b" would remain in the output. You will see it after new "a", "b" and "c" will be added to the table. The same is true for "d" (because removing of "c" causes table length reducing by 1) and for "f" (because removing of "e" causes one more table length reducing).

The solution is just to decrement iteration variable after the row is removed:

```
  for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
      row = rows[j];
      console.log(row.cells[0].innerHTML);
      for (var k = 0; k < letters.length; k++) {
          var letter = letters[k];
          if (row.cells[0].innerHTML === letter)
          {
              tab.deleteRow(j);
              j--;
              break;
          }
      }
  }
```

I also prepared Plunker for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/L7ieHFLGob6ikL5YJsaD?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes perfect sense once you say it, but I couldn't get my head around it. Your solution worked perfectly. Best regards.

Comment: @Protium You are welcome! use Plunker to demo your issues next time, the demo will make it much easier to help you.